# Unable to mock Class property set in constructor

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-test

I have been trying to write a junit for a class where I have set its properties using a application properties provided config. The config is iterated and set in ElasticSearchConnections.

But when I try mocking the behavior it just creates a object with null value for the property.
The service class where the constructor is using ElasticSearchConnections to create ElasticSearchServiceOperation.

```
@Service
public class AuditElasticService {
    private final Map<String,ElasticSearchOperationsService> elasticSearchOperationsServiceMap;

    public AuditElasticService(ElasticSearchConnections elasticSearchConnections) {
        this.elasticSearchOperationsServiceMap = elasticSearchConnections.applyToAllConnections(ElasticSearchOperationsService::new);
    }

    public void createAliases(String ssid, EnvironmentStage environmentStage) {
        String aliasName = "testAudit;
        String indexNameTemplate = "testTemplate";
        String environment = EnvironmentStage.PRODUCTION.equals(environmentStage) ? "prod" : "dev";

        elasticSearchOperationsServiceMap.get(environment).addAliases(aliasName, indexNameTemplate);
    }
}
```

Config class where its ElasticSearchConfiguration is fetched from application properties:

```
@Component
public class ElasticSearchConnections {
    @Getter
    private final Map<String, ElasticSearchConnection> connections;
    private ElasticSearchConfigurations elasticSearchConfigurations;

    public ElasticSearchConnections(ElasticSearchConfigurations elasticSearchConfigurations) {
        connections = elasticSearchConfigurations.getConfigurationMap().entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, this::getElasticSearchConnection));
    }

    private ElasticSearchConnection getElasticSearchConnection(Map.Entry<String, ElasticSearchConfiguration> entry) {
        ElasticSearchConfiguration elasticSearchConfiguration = entry.getValue();
        return new ElasticSearchConnection(elasticSearchConfiguration, new KeyTabCookieProvider(elasticSearchConfiguration.getKerberosDetail()));
    }

    public ElasticSearchConnection getByEnv(String environment) {
        return connections.get(environment);
    }

    public <T> Map<String, T> applyToAllConnections(Function<ElasticSearchConnection, T> function) {
        return connections.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, function.compose(Map.Entry::getValue)));
    }

}
```

Junit where I tried to mock the ElasticSearchOperationsMap property with a mock of ElasticSearchConnections. Adding in a when replacement is not picked up. It gives me java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.gs.controleng.flowservice.service.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchOperationsService.addAliases(String, String)" because the return value of "java.util.Map.get(Object)" is null
:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class AuditElasticServiceTest {

    private AuditElasticService auditElasticService;
    @Mock
    private ElasticSearchConnections elasticSearchConnections;
    @Mock
    private ElasticSearchOperationsService elasticSearchOperationsService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        auditElasticService = new AuditElasticService(elasticSearchConnections);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("should create a new flow when provided with a title")
    void testCreateAliases() {
        String aliasName = "testAudit";
        String indexNameTemplate = "testTemplate";
        when(elasticSearchConnections.applyToAllConnections(any())).thenReturn(Map.of("dev", elasticSearchOperationsService));
        doNothing().when(elasticSearchOperationsService).addAliases(aliasName, indexNameTemplate);

        auditElasticService.createAliases(testSsid, EnvironmentStage.DEVELOPMENT);

        verify(elasticSearchConnections, times(1)).applyToAllConnections(any());
        verify(elasticSearchOperationsService, times(1)).addAliases(aliasName, indexNameTemplate);
    }

}
```

Comment: The production class calls `elasticSearchConfigurations.getConfigurationMap()` at the very beginning. This method is never stubbed, it will return an empty map. Thus, `connections` in your class are always empty. And `.get` on an empty map will return null (because the map does not contain anything)

Comment: @knittl But in the junit I am passing a Mock object of eleasticSearchConnections to AuditElasticService constructor. I do see the mock elasticSearchConnections being passed to it in runtime.

Comment: Yes, but passing a mock doesn't make the mock magically return valid configuration entries from the `getConfigurationMap()` method. It will return an empty map, unless manually stubbed.

Comment: @knittl sorry I did stub it but it actually makes the elasticsearch call then, how could I avoid that without mocking

Comment: It's not stubbed in the code in the question, so your example is not reproducable. Please [edit] the question to include a proper [mre].

Comment: You set up your mock elasticSearchConnections *after* you've created the AuditElasticService, which calls applyToAllConnections in its constructor.